# jQuery .bind method not activating the second time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an element, which fills the screen. Under that I have another element which does NOT fill the screen but is hidden. So you can't manually scroll to that.

The first element which is filling the screen has the following CSS properties:

```
header {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: green;
}
```

And the second element has these CSS properties:

```
#content {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    height: 1500px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

I use this code to trace the scrolling:

```
$('header').bind("DOMMouseScroll mousewheel", function(e) {
   ...
});
```

Inside this method I check which panel is activated (by a self created boolean) and which direction I'm scrolling to, by doing this:

```
$('header').bind("DOMMouseScroll mousewheel", function(e) {
    var wheelDelta = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
    if (active === header && wheelDelta <= 0) {
        ...

    }
});
```

Inside that if statement I give call a method that displays the `#content` element below it and smoothly scrolls to it, and when its done scrolling it hides the element where we have scrolled from (`header`). I'm using this piece of code for that:

```
$('body').bind("DOMMouseScroll mousewheel", function (e) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var wheelDelta = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
    $('header').unbind("DOMMouseScroll mousewheel");
    if (active === header && wheelDelta <= 0) {
        showScrollHide(500, content, 1000, header, 250, function () {
            _window.scrollTop(0);
            _scrollBackBtn.fadeIn();
            active = content;
        });
    }
});
```

This works perfectly, whenever I scroll down on the `header` element while its active. It smoothly scrolls down to the `#content` element under it.

There I have a button which scrolls back up the page, I have this code for it:

```
_scrollBackBtn.on('click', function() {
    if (active === content) {
        active = header;
        scrollBackHide(header, content, 500, 250, function() {
            window.location = '#';
        });
    }
});
```

Which also works perfectly, it scrolls back to the top of the page.

But whenever I try to scroll down again, it doesn't do anything. How does this come?

I had to add `$('header').unbind("DOMMouseScroll mousewheel");` to the code, otherwise it looked very ugly in the end result.

Whenever I added `$('header').stop();` in the same section, it didn't make any difference.

So my question is. How can this `.bind` method be used again for the same thing?

**[Here's a demo if you don't understand what I mean. Whenever you scroll down on the `header` element, and scroll back up via the button. Its not doing the same again.](http://jsfiddle.net/N7PD7/10/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are unbinding your mousewheel handlers when they run once and then never re-binding them, so there are no event handlers in place to react to mousewheel events after you click the button. Re-binding that event handler when you click the button does the trick.

[Here is a fiddle that does that and should point you in the right direction.](http://jsfiddle.net/ZM48m/1/)

I pulled your mousewheel handler out into a function so we can reuse it whenever we need to bind those events:

```
var handleMouseWheel = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();    
    var wheelDelta = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
    if (active === header && wheelDelta <= 0) {
        $('body').unbind("DOMMouseScroll mousewheel");
        showScrollHide(500, content, 1000, header, 250, function () {
            _window.scrollTop(0);
            _scrollBackBtn.fadeIn();
            active = content;
        });
    }        
};
```

and use that to reattach an event handler when the button is clicked:

```
_scrollBackBtn.on('click', function () {
    if (active === content) {
        scrollBackHide(header, content, 500, 250, function () {
            window.location = '#';
            active = header;
        });

        $('body').bind("DOMMouseScroll mousewheel", handleMouseWheel);
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks man :D I already solved it but this was the exact same answer so yeah :P, But can i do something like `$('header').bind(...........);` aswell? And what does that then? @ajm

Comment: Sure, you can bind to whatever you like as long as you bind again after unbinding.

Comment: But what's the difference when i `bind` on `body` or i bind on `header`? Is it that i can only scroll on `header` then?

Comment: Yes, you would have to initiate a scroll from the header. Binding to the document gives you a much bigger target to work with, but it's up to you.